# I want to select the distinct value from models field and then update them (django)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have models...

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Item Name', max_length = 30)
    item_code = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    color = models.CharField(max_length = 150, null = True, blank = True)
    size = models.CharField(max_length = 30, null = True, blank = True)
    fabric_code = models.CharField(max_length = 30, null = True, blank = True)
```

I have values in Item. In the Item model name field has the similar values (but the other values of record are changed). I want to select the name field values distinctly (ie similar values select only ones) in one box (like combo box).

What kind of form or views can I use?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question. Do you want to select distinct values for name, as in

```
Item.objects.values('name').distinct()
```

Comment: yes, i want similar this. but how can i use it with in form ??
like
item = forms.ModelChoiceField(label = 'Select Item', queryset = Item.objects.values('name').distinct()) it does not work.
)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change a widget choices items, use something like this :

```
choices_list = Item.objects.values_list('name','name').distinct()
form_item = forms.ModelChoiceField(label = 'Select Item', choices = choices_list)
```

As said in the [django field docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField.choices) :

**choices** : An iterable (e.g., a list or tuple) of 2-tuples to use as choices for this field.

Comment: I use this but i also want to add the first empty field? the above code does not add empty value

Comment: choices_list = list(Item.objects.values_list('name','name').distinct())
choices_list.insert(0, ('', '------'))